# Ruby - How to represent message length as 2 binary bytes

Tags: ruby, sockets, binary, byte

I'm using Ruby and I'm communicating with a network endpoint that requires the formatting of a 'header' prior to sending the message itself.

The first field in the header must be the message length which is defined as a 2 binary byte message length in network byte order.

For example, my message is 1024 in length.  How do I represent 1024 as binary two-bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard tools for byte wrangling in Ruby (and Perl and Python and ...) are `pack` and `unpack`. Ruby's [`pack` is in `Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack). You have a length that should be two bytes long and in network byte order, that sounds like a job for the `n` format specifier:

> n | Integer | 16-bit unsigned, network (big-endian) byte order

So if the length is in `length`, you'd get your two bytes thusly:

```
two_bytes = [ length ].pack('n')
```

If you need to do the opposite, have a look at [`String#unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
length = two_bytes.unpack('n').first
```

Answer (score 5):

See [Array#pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack).

```
[1024].pack("n")
```

This packs the number as the network-order byte sequence `\x04\x00`.

The way this works is that each byte is 8 binary bits. 1024 in binary is `10000000000`. If we break this up into octets of 8 (8 bits per byte), we get: `00000100 00000000`.

A byte can represent (2 states) ^ (8 positions) = 256 unique values. However, since we don't have 256 ascii-printable characters, we visually represent bytes as hexadecimal pairs, since a hexadecimal digit can represent 16 different values and 16 * 16 = 256. Thus, we can take the first byte, `00000100` and break it into two hexadecimal quads as `0000 0100`. Translating binary to hex gives us `0x04`. The second byte is trivial, as `0000 0000` is `0x00`. This gives us our hexadecimal representation of the two-byte string.

It's worth noting that because you are constrained to a 2-byte (16-bit) header, you are limited to a maximum value of `11111111 11111111`, or 2^16 - 1 = `65535` bytes. Any message larger than that cannot accurately represent its length in two bytes.