# send xml data via socket with message (VLI) Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, sockets

Ruby novice. First time post so excuse any communication protocol inadequacies :)

This site has been a great help and a "HUGE!!!" shoutout of thanks to all.

I need to connect my rails app to an electricity providers api so I can vend electricity to my web customers. I'm needing some help to simply get an initial request sent to the API

IP: 41.204.194.188
Port: 8945

First block: What is a message variable length indicator (VLI)?

"2 bytes precede every message sent to/from BizSwitch. The 2 bytes are referred to as a variable length indicator. Bytes 1-2 indicate the number of bytes in the message (excluding the first 2 bytes). The 2 bytes represent a 16bit unsigned integer in network byte order. Note that if a compressed message is being sent, the message will have to first be compressed, in order to determine its length, before being sent."

Ignore compression.

link to api doc: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3815995/Ipay-prepaidElecTransactionSpec.pdf

Simple Vend Request example:

```
<ipayMsg client="ipay" term="1" seqNum="0" time="2002-05-16 10:55:30 +0200"> 
<elecMsg ver="2.37">
<vendReq> 
<ref>136105500001</ref> 
<amt cur="ZAR">11400</amt> 
<numTokens>1</numTokens> 
<meter>A12C3456789</meter>
<payType>cash</payType>
</vendReq > 
</elecMsg>
</ipayMsg>
```

Simple Vend Response example

```
<ipayMsg client="ipay" term="1" seqNum="0" time="2002-05-16 10:55:35 +0200">
<elecMsg ver="2.37"
<vendRes> <ref>136105500001</ref>
<res code="elec000">OK</res>
<util addr="Megawatt Park, Contact Centre tel 086-003-7566" taxRef="4740101508" distId="6004708001509">Eskom Online</util>
<stdToken units="346.34" rctNum="12345678" amt="10000" tax="1400">12345678901234567890</stdToken>
<rtlrMsg>060000 Warning: This meter is not configured for FBE.</rtlrMsg>
<customerMsg>Meter not registered for Free Basic Electricity. Please apply at your local office.</customerMsg>
</vendRes>
</elecMsg>
</ipayMsg>
```

I've got this far and I seem connected but how do I actually send and receive responses? I've tried googling for help but yet to find how to send the XML packet and then receive the response.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'socket'

begin
 socket = TCPSocket.new('41.204.194.188', 8945)
rescue => e
 puts "error: #{e}"
else
 puts "connected"
end
socket.close
```

Would appreciate any assistance or a nudge in the right direction.

Kind regards,

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Great I figured it out. Main issue regarding communication to the socket was sending a message variable length indicator. This stackoverflow question put me on the write path "[Ruby - How to represent message length as 2 binary bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794817/ruby-how-to-represent-message-length-as-2-binary-bytes)"

Step 1: determine the length of my xml message length = message.size

The first field in the header must be the message length which is defined as a 2 binary byte message length in network byte order.

Step 2: message_variable_length_indicator = [length].pack("n")

Step 3: Connect to socket streamSock = TCPSocket::new('41.204.194.188', 8945)

Step 4: streamSock.write(message_variable_length_indicator)

Step 5: streamSock.write(message)

Step 6: get a response str = streamSock.recvfrom(1000)

Now to deal with timeout but at least I'm connecting :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in PHP may be you will get idea from below code its working fine for my request.

```
function sendSocketRequest($XmlString, $Socket_Request) {
    if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    if (!socket_connect($sock, $Socket_Request['HostName'], $Socket_Request['Port'])) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    $status = socket_write($sock, pack_int32be(strlen($XmlString)), 4);
    $status = socket_write($sock, $XmlString, strlen($XmlString));
    $response = socket_read($sock, $this->_socketReadLength);

    socket_close($sock);
    return substr($response, 2);
}

function pack_int32be($i) {
    if ($i < -2147483648 || $i > 2147483647) {
        die("Out of bounds");
    }
    return pack('C4', ($i >> 24) & 0xFF, ($i >> 16) & 0xFF, ($i >> 8) & 0xFF, ($i >> 0) & 0xFF
    );
}
$socketResponse = sendSocketRequest($yourXMLString, array('HostName'=>'<HostName>','Port'=>'<Port>');
```